# Chart with a Dual Category Axis - Possible with Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, data-visualization

Is it possible to create a chart with the one below with Highcharts? It has nested/dual categories in the bottom axis.

If so, are there any examples I can look at please?

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/ . https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories

Comment: @Deep3015 thank god highcharts can do this! thanks a lot Deep :)